# How do I execute App Engine Go SDK delay package on a different module?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have an app with several modules. A `dispatch.yaml` file routes all `*/api/*` calls from my `default` module to my `server` module.

The following request chain happens:

1. http://myapp.appspot.com/api/webrequest - Note we are on the default module.
2. http://server-dot-myapp.appspot.com/api/webrequest - Redirection with `dispatch.yaml` to the server module where `appengine.delay.Call` is made using the [delay package](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay).
3. http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/queue/go/delay - The `appengine.delay.Func` is called on the default module instead of http://server-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/queue/go/delay like I would expect.

How can I make my `appengine.delay.Func` execute with http://server-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/queue/go/delay?

Note that if I call http://server-dot-myapp.appspot.com/api/webrequest directly without using the `dispatch.yaml` redirect, everything workes as expected and `appengine.delay.Func` gets called with http://server-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/queue/go/delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an incongruity in App Engine. See [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/xpbmqrsySeE) discussion for further information.

Essentially instead of using `appengine.delay.Call` you use `appengine.delay.Task` and set the `Host` param to the module host name you want:

```
t := myDelayFunc.Task("myparam")
t.Header = make(map[string][]string)

hostName, err := appengine.ModuleHostname(context, "[your module name]", "", "")
t.Header.Set("Host", hostName)
taskqueue.Add(context, t)
```

Comment: It's not a bug. The `appengine/delay` package is, by its nature, a convenience package. The `Call` method targets the task at the default module, since that's what most people want; as you've seen, you can use the `Task` method to have more control over where it is sent.

Comment: @dsymonds I'd probably agree that there isn't a bug in appengine/delay - you would know. However, I find it inconsistent that the Call method targets the non-default module if it is executed by a request handler also on the non-default module. However if the same request handler is called via a request that has passed through dispatch.yaml then the Call method will target the default module even though it is also executed on the non-default module. This must be a bug/oversight?

Comment: It's a minor oddity of how taskqueues work in general, which is what `appengine/delay` builds on. I agree it's somewhat unexpected, but I think it's something that can't be changed now without breaking some apps.